# Blazor release managed and unmanaged resource

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side, idisposable

I am creating a server side Blazor application and want to release managed and unmanaged resource correctly. I am beginner of Blazor and not sure if what I did is correct or not. Please give me some instructions. Thanks

//This is my service for city model

```
namespace MyApplication.Services
{
    public class BasCityService : IBasCityService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<BasCity> _cityRepository;
        private readonly ISysExceptionLogService _exceptionLogService;

        public BasCityService(IGenericRepository<BasCity> cityRepository,  
         ISysExceptionLogService exceptionLogService)
        {
            _cityRepository = cityRepository;
            _exceptionLogService = exceptionLogService;

        }

        public async Task<BasCity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _cityRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await _exceptionLogService?.CreateLogAsync(ex, null, 
              "BasCityService.GetByIdAsync()");
                return null;
            }
          
        }
 
 
        //Other 
        ............
        
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _cityRepository.Dispose(true); //In GenericRepository do  _dbContext.Dispose();
            _exceptionLogService.Dispose();
             
        }

}
```

//This is city details razor page

```
@page "/Base/City/CityDetails/{id:int}"
@inject IBasCityService cityService
@inject ISysExceptionLogService exceptionLogService

.........

@code {


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        city = new BasCity();

        try
        {
            city = await cityService?.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (city == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Can't find City object by Id");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await processError?.LogError(Exception ex);

        }


    }
    
    
    .............
    
    
     //Dispose resource

    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposedValue;

    ~CityDetails() => Dispose(false);

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)

                city = null;

            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
            // TODO: set large fields to null

            cityService?.Dispose();
            if (cityService != null) cityService = null;
            exceptionLogService?.Dispose();
            if (exceptionLogService != null) exceptionLogService = null;
            _disposedValue = true;                  

        }
    }   

}
```

Please tell me if CityDetails page changes to other page such as CityList page. cityService & exceptionLogService resource can be disposed correctly by the finalizer. Also what managed resource we usually need to clean up inside   // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)? Thank you very much